# Symfony embedded order form map data back

Tags: symfony, collections, symfony-forms

I'm creating a order form with embedded data like orderItems (collection) in Symfony 4.5.
My OrderType look like this:

```
<?php
class OrderType extends BaseOrderType
{
    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
    {
        $builder->add('note', TextareaType::class, array(
            'label' => 'order.note_company',
            'required' => false,
        ));

        $builder->add('orderItems', CollectionType::class, array(
            'entry_type' => OrderItemType::class,
            'entry_options' => array(
                'label' => false
            ),
            'allow_add' => true,
            'prototype_data' => new OrderItem()
        ));
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver): void
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => Order::class,
            'translation_domain' => 'forms',
        ));
    }
}
```

And for my embedded form OrderItemType

```
<?php
class OrderItemType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
    {
        $builder->add('amount', IntegerType::class, array(
            'label' => 'order.amount',
            'attr' => array(
                'min' => 0,
            ),
            'data' => 1,
            'required' => false,
        ));

        $builder->add('configureProductType', ConfigureProductType::class, array(
            'label' => false,
            'show_submit_btn' => false,
            'required' => false,
        ));
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver): void
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => OrderItem::class,
            'translation_domain' => 'forms',
            'allow_extra_fields' => true
        ));
    }
}
```

The OrderItemType contains a field configureProductType which is also a form with reusable fields, like product, price, etc. But how could this field configureProductType be mapped back to the original OrderItemType.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the [`inherit_data` option](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/inherit_data_option.html). The symfony docs explain this in detail, but all you need is to set the `inherit_data` option to `true` for your nested form type:

```php
// in ConfigureProductType
public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults([
        'inherit_data' => true,
        'data_class' => OrderItem::class
    ]);
}
```

There is one caveat to using `inherit_data` that you need to be aware of. From the symfony docs:

> Forms with the inherit_data option set cannot have *_SET_DATA event listeners.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is that ConfigureProductType uses *_SET_DATA

Let me share that code to

```
<?php
class ConfigureProductType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
    {
        $product = $options['product'];        
        $orderItem = $options['data'];        

        // Type.
        $builder->add('type', ChoiceType::class, array(
            'label' => 'configure_product.type.label',
            'choices' => ProductHelper::getOrderTypes($product),
            'choice_label' => function($choice, $key, $value) {
                return sprintf('configure_product.type.choices.%s', $choice);
            },
            'constraints' => array(
                new NotBlank(array('message' => 'configure_product.type.not_blank')),
            ),
            'attr' => array(
                'class' => 'configure-product-type'
            ),
            'empty_data' => $orderItem->getType() ?? ProductHelper::TYPE_ORDER_DEFAULT,
            'expanded' => true,
        ));

        $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::POST_SET_DATA, function(FormEvent $event) use ($options) {
            if (null === $item = $event->getData()) {
                return;
            }

            $form = $event->getForm();

            $form->add('length', IntegerType::class, array(
                'label' => 'configure_product.length',
                'attr' => array(
                    'min' => static::LENGTH_MIN,
                ),
                'empty_data' => '100',
            ));

            $form->add('width', IntegerType::class, array(
                'label' => 'configure_product.width',
                'attr' => array(
                    'min' => static::WIDTH_MIN,
                    'step' => static::WIDTH_STEP,
                ),
                'empty_data' => '100',
            ));
        });
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver): void
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => OrderItem::class,
            'translation_domain' => 'forms',
            'product' => null,
        ));
    }
}
```

As you could see ConfigureProduct Type needs a product and an order item option data and uses *_SET_DATE. Let me explain it some more.
ConfigureProductType is a form used in the frontend of the application to configure a product. At this point product data is know in the form.

In the backend we want to use the same ConfigureProductType form but now you need to select an product first, then an ajax request submits the form so that the form knows the product but then, how could we reuse ConfigureProductType. Trying to call parent::buildform in the event listener but it's not working, see example below (second approach with extend ConfigureProductType)

```
<?php
class OrderItemType extends ConfigureProductType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
    {
        $builder->add('amount', IntegerType::class, array(
            'label' => 'order.amount',
            'attr' => array(
                'min' => 0,
            ),
            'data' => 1,
            'required' => false,
        ));

        $builder->add('configureProductType', ConfigureProductType::class, array(
            'label' => false,
            'show_submit_btn' => false,
            'required' => false,
        ));

        $orderItemModifier = function(FormInterface $form, OrderItem $orderItem, $eventType = null) use ($builder, $options) {
            if(null === $product = $orderItem->getProduct()) {
                return;
            }

            // how to rebuild options with selected product and then call parent
            // parent::buildForm($builder, $options); ??
        };

        $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA, function(FormEvent $event) use ($orderItemModifier) {
            $form = $event->getForm();

            if(null === $orderItem = $event->getData()) {
                return;
            }

            $orderItemModifier($form, $orderItem, FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA);
        });

        $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::SUBMIT, function(FormEvent $event) use ($orderItemModifier) {
            $form = $event->getForm();

            if(null === $orderItem = $event->getData()) {
                return;
            }

            $orderItemModifier($form, $orderItem, FormEvents::SUBMIT);
        });
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver): void
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => OrderItem::class,
            'translation_domain' => 'forms',
            'allow_extra_fields' => true
        ));
    }
}
```